# Pass wrong values by menu items when using drupal_get_form

Tags: php, drupal-6

I want to send a parameter to my function with drupal_get_form() in the menu item, but not works and wrong values send i don't have any idea about this error.

First i call the menu item from this line in onther file:

```
drupal_goto( 'a/b/c/d/'.$form_state['values']['number']);
```

here is my menu item code in a different file:

```
$items['a/b/c/d/%'] = array(
    'title' =>t('report'),
    'description' => 'my report',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('make_report',1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('admin'),
    'file' => 'report_file.inc',        
);
```

and this is my function header in report_file.inc:

```
function make_report(&$form_state,$back=0){
.
.
```

this is the variable dump of $form_state:

storage (NULL)
submitted (Boolean) FALSE
post (Array, 0 elements)

this is the variable dump of $back:
b

i want the $back pass '1' but it get the second level of my url.